# Linq - Set int to 0 if it is a minus number

Tags: c#, linq

I'm initialising a class object using Linq, what I need to do is set a value of 0 if I find the value from another class object is a minus number, here's the existing code:

```
public void fillObject(FillData dataToAdd)
{
    Data data = new Data();

    Data.Items = dataToAdd.maindata
        .select(
            x => new Data.ItemsStruct
                     {
                         parameter1inItemsStruct = x.intno1,
                         parameter1inItemsStruct = x.intno2
                     });
}
```

`intno1` or `intno2` can be any value but if the value is a negative number I want to set it to 0.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be acheived in `LINQ`? What I don't want to do is directly reference each parameter in the object and check/alter its value, I just want to check/change the value 'inline' with `Linq`.

Comment: Anonymous functions are not limited to a single expression. `x => new Something(x)` can also be written as `x => { return new Something(x); }`, and that notation allows multiple statements/expressions.

Comment: Thanks, that also helps with my future dev :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Math.Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cs0a3045(v=vs.110).aspx) for that:

```
parameter1inItemsStruct = Math.Max(0, x.intno1),
parameter1inItemsStruct = Math.Max(0, x.intno2)
```

Comment: Aha thanks, so it compares 0 to the variable and returns the maximum sum, in this case 0 is always higher than a minus number but anything over 0 will be the accepted value?

Comment: @DanHall It returns the larger value (not the sum). If you look at the implementation, it is: `val1 >= val2 ? val1 : val2`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**?: Operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
{
    parameter1inItemsStruct = x.intno1 > 0 ? x.intro1 : 0,
    parameter1inItemsStruct = x.intno2 > 0 ? x.intro2 : 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public void fillObject(FillData dataToAdd)
{
Data data = new Data();

Data.Items = dataToAdd.maindata
.select(x => new Data.ItemsStruct
{

parameter1inItemsStruct = x.intno1<0?0:x.intno1,
parameter1inItemsStruct = x.intno2<0?0:x.intno2

});

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this: `parameter1inItemsStruct = x.intno1 < 0 ? 0 : x.intno1`